# Cyclic dependency with logger and filesystem class

Tags: object-oriented

I have a cyclic dependency in my architecture design.

Let's assume there are the following modules:

**FileSystem** (uses Logger)

Handles file operations like reading, writing files etc.
**This module should log its actions.** The logger is injected via dependency injection.

---

**NullLogger** (implements Logger)

Discards all log messages.

---

**FileLogger** (implements Logger)

Writes log messages to the file system.
Should internally use the `FileSystem` module to reduce code duplication. (See where its going?)

---

**ConsoleLogger** (implements Logger)

Writes log messages directly to the console.

---

The problem (if its not clear by now):

- I pass `ConsoleLogger` to `FileSystem` and everything works fine.
- I pass `FileLogger` to `FileSystem`, and poof! It won't work because those two modules are recursively dependent on each other so I won't be able to instantiate either of them.

I can only think of one possible way to avoid the problem:

FileLogger instantiates it's own FileSystem with a `NullLogger` (or any other Logger except `FileLogger`). Drawback: I would not be able to see any log messages (in the file) from the FileLogger itself.

But I'm not sure if that's the route I should go for.

Comment: If your logger infrastructure also logs its own actions, then you will get such an explosion of log messages that the noise from the logging infrastructure will completely drown the useful information from the rest of the application.

Comment: an Interface described by a new component which the other two subscribe to would alleviate your dependency problem

Comment: This would be much simpler if you stick to your application concerns.  The app shouldn't care where logs go, it doesn't matter. If you always log go standard out and standard error, your environment can decide to redirect those streams to a file or database or web service or anywhere else. Check out 12factor.net

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I pass FileLogger to FileSystem, and poof! It won't work because those two modules are recursively dependent on each other so I won't be able to instantiate either of them.

I think it is debatable if a `FileSystem` module really needs logging at its core, or if this concern should be solved on a different level, like suggested by Ben Cotrell, but anyway, let us assume your requirement is justified for some reason.

Logs of `FileSystem` calls should be written to a **different file** than the log file used by, for example, an application which instantiates a file logger for a different purpose. So there should be two `FileLogger` objects in this scenario, each one associated with a different *file*. And since each of your `FileSystem` objects holds a reference to a specific file logger, this leads to the need of having **two different file system objects as well**, where the first one is initialized with a null logger and the second one with the logger for file system calls. In pseudo code:

```
 FileSystem nonLoggingFileSystem = new FileSystem(new NullLogger());

 FileLogger fileSysCallsLogger("file_system_calls.log", nonLoggingFileSystem);

 FileSystem fileSystem = new FileSystem(fileSysCallsLogger);

 FileLogger applicationCallsLogger(`application_calls.log`, fileSystem);
```

Now there is no cyclic dependency between the involved objects, and `fileSystem` as well as `applicationCallsLogger` can be used safely inside the application, without any recursion.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was going for :)

Comment: Interesting 1st sentence. Reminds me of admonitions against (unit) testing a framework.

Comment: @radarbob: don't get me wrong, logging in combination with file system operations can make a lot sense. However, I think Ben Cottrell's approach to create a file system component without any logging code first and then use decorating techniques to create a logging file system on top is not bad and also a valid solution, that is why I wrote "it is debatable".

Answer (score 3):

***Update to clarify the intent of this answer:***
The question identifies two separate responsibilities as per [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) - logging and file I/O.   One of the options presented in the question is to inject a `NullLogger` which does nothing.    An alternative to injecting a do-nothing `NullLogger` could be to write a standalone class to handle the boundary which has no interest in logging, then handle the logging higher up, and eliminating the need for a `NullLogger`.

---

Consider splitting the behaviour of your `FileSystem` between the code which actually performs the I/O and that code which decides if/when to perform any related logging (e.g. `LoggedFileSystem`).

You could have a simple `FileSystem` class which performs no logging, and is only used by the Logger, and by the `LoggedFileSystem`, while the rest of the system uses `LoggedFileSystem` for all of its File I/O.

For example:

```
// The "raw" I/O class.
public class FileSystem 
{
    public byte[] Read(string filename) { /* ..etc. */ }
    public void Write(byte[] data, string filename) { /* ..etc. */ }
}

// Used by the rest of the system for its I/O operations
public class LoggedFileSystem
{
    private FileSystem _fileSystem = new FileSystem();

    public byte[] Read(string filename) 
    { 
        try 
        {
            Logger.Debug($"Reading file {filename}...");
            var data = _fileSystem.Read(fileName);
            Logger.Debug($"Successfully read {filename} - {data.Length} bytes");
            return data;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error($"Exception handled reading {filename}", ex);
            throw;
        }
    }

    public void Write(byte[] data, string filename) 
    { 
        try 
        {
            Logger.Debug($"Writing {data.Length} bytes to {filename}");
            var data = _fileSystem.Read(fileName);
            Logger.Debug($"FileSystem.Write succeeded.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error($"Exception handled writing to {filename}", ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

In summary, this alternative suggestion is functionally equivalent to one of the original suggestions of injecting a `NullLogger into a`FileSystem`.  The result is

- A `FileSystem` class which has no logging,
- A `LoggedFileSystem` class with the same methods as `FileSystem` (to be used in the same way from an outsider perspective), but which also handles logging.

---

**Update**:
As a side note: you might still inject the `Logger` into the `LoggedFileSystem` as per some of the other alternative solutions, in case that's needed for any reason:

```
public class LoggedFileSystem
{
    private FileSystem _fileSystem = new FileSystem();
    private ILogger _logger;

    public LoggedFileSystem(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

Comment: What would be the benefit of this solution over just passing a `NullLogger` to `FileSystem` for the `FileLogger`?

Comment: @d3l They're functionally equivalent, but this approach is about keeping with the [Single Responsibility Principle (SRP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).  A class representing File I/O is an external *boundary*, so ideally its responsibility would be limited just to I/O concerns.  If the class also decides when and what to log that starts to look like a violation of SRP.    Logic for Logging is one of those cross-cutting concerns, similar to Caching;  this approach is about catering for cross-cutting concerns without touching the actual 'boundary' (I/O) logic.

Comment: I disagree with your conception of "responsibility" in this case. Responsibility is a subjective concept and should change according to the abstraction level.

Comment: @FrankHileman To clarify, I'm not basing it on subjective opinion; I linked to the wikipedia page for [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), so please assume I am referring to that definition.  The question asker has identified two separate responsibilities - logging and file I/O, so the fact that these are indeed separate responsibilities seems to be a "given" (being that it's the entire basis for the question);  this answer is an alternative way of splitting those responsibilities by isolating the *boundary* entirely.

Comment: @FrankHileman Added extra context information at the top of the answer with the hope it clarifies 'responsibility' in more objective terms.

Comment: If logging uses file I/O, from a higher level of abstraction, that responsibility "logging" may include i/o. This is what I mean by subjective. While there are advantages in separating in them at the lower level, depending on the design, we have to congregate responsibilities in order to form higher level abstractions. I am always in favor of the simpler solution.

Comment: Responsibility is a vague term both on the wikipedia page and in the book. If applied strictly ("reason to change"), all our software would be terrribly bloated, as we could never create higher level abstractions, and it provides fuel for those that seek to create extremely fragmented software.

Comment: @FrankHileman Nowhere am I suggesting that any rules should be applied strictly; I hope I made it clear in my update that the answer is a suggestion of an alternative (which is functionally equivalent, and essentially no more or less complex) to an option presented in the question.    The question itself identified Logging and File I/O as separate responsibilities; indeed the entire premise of the question is about how to separate these two concerns.   I'm afraid that I really don't understand why you feel that this is a problem on this occasion.  How would you actually improve the answer?.

Comment: @BenCottrell I agree with others that it is a bit silly to have the circular dependency in the first place. So I think eliminating that as mentioned, a logger might use the file system but the file system does not use the logger, makes the most sense. But Doc Brown provides the simplest solution. No one explained why dependency injection is needed at all here.

Comment: @FrankHileman well we seem to both agree on most of that.  Doc Brown's answer is certainly simpler.   I don't think that makes anything about this answer invalid or irrelvant to the question though, as usual with anything on SE there is rarely a single correct solution!      Dependency Injection isn't really relevant to the main part of the answer - it was just an extra update based on an earlier comment.    Can we both at least agree that the answer is both valid and relevant with regards to the question?    Otherwise I'm really struggling to understand the reason for the feedback/downvote.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your objects don't do any useful work in their constructors, it is possible to resolve cyclic dependencies in dependency injection by using property injection.

For example, if your FileLogger defers opening its file until first called to log something, you could initialise your system like this:

```
FileLogger logger = new FileLogger();
FileSystem filesystem = new FileSystem (logger);
logger.setFileSystem (filesystem);
```

You could also choose to break the cycle the other way, by injecting the file system's logger as a property.

It would be important for FileLogger to have a good way of recovering if used before the file system property is set (perhaps storing messages in a buffer and logging them at the first opportunity).

Comment: I thought of that but this solution requires the logger to be aware of the FileSystem, which I want to avoid at all cost.

Comment: Then break it the other way. Initialise FileSystem with a MemoryLogger, then when the FileLogger is initialized, change ît to the FileLogger and dump anything in the MemoryLogger's buffer into the FileLogger.